# Flash Builder 4.5 target player

Tags: flash, actionscript, builder, flashcatalyst

I am importing a Catalyst project into FB 4.5 and keep getting the same error over and over.
Here's the error I am getting:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The target Flash Player version 10.0.45.0 specified should be equal or higher than 
the minimum version 10.2.0.0 required by Flex SDK.  Project Name    
Unknown Flex Problem
```

I have the latest Flash Player installed and using the 4.5 sdk. I ahve also tried with 3.6 sdk and 4.0 sdk

How can I change the target FP settings in FB 4.5? Is this even what I need to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it is an Air App there is the APP Configuration file yourapp-app.xml

Somewhere in the headsection is the flex framework ersion defined. Simply Update it to at least 10.2.0.0